# jQuery append divs

Tags: jquery

I want to append divs to a parent div, each smaller div being a random background color chosen from an array. How would I do so?

What I already have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var cell_size = 10;
    var container = $("#container");
    var colors = ["limepulp", "goldgreen", "chromeoxidegreen", "kermit", "pear"];

    /* Get the cell dimentions and populate the grid */
    var cell_height_num = container.height() / cell_size;   /* This is equal to 50 */
    var cell_width_num = container.width() / cell_size;     /* This is also equal to 50 */

    for (var i = 0; i < cell_width_num * cell_height_num; i++){

         /* What goes here? How can I generate a div with a random background comming from colors[]? */
         /* In total, 2500 divs should be generated inside $("#container"); */

    }

});
```

Comment: This will be quite slow on some machines... 2500 divs is a lot.  I think you should look into using `canvas`

Comment: That's a crapload of divs. This is probably better suited for server side...

Comment: @Hogan takes about 200ms to render for me.

Comment: @Raynos - still your example is a table... did you try the div?

Comment: @Hogan do you think 2500 divs is slower then 2500 tds ?

Comment: @Raynos - I do -- tds are a sub control of a table and I expect will typically require less processing for page based operations and searches (just the table will get looked at).  Sure it is a guess but if I were to write a dom handler that is how I would implement it.

Answer (score 1):

```
var colors = [ 'red', 'blue', 'green', '#ffe' ];
...
for (var i = 0; i < cell_width_num * cell_height_num; i++) {
    var color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
    $('#container').append(
        $('<div/>', {
            style: 'background-color:' + color,
            text: 'some text'
        })
    );
}
```

Also note that colors contained in the colors array are not valid CSS color names. You could use the #RGB equivalent to define them.

Comment: @Jason McCreary, yes they might. The code could be easily adapted to use `class` instead of `style` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

This is better suited to a `<table>`

[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/Raynos/4dVfK/23/)

code:

```
/* Get the cell dimentions and populate the grid */
var cell_height_num = 50; /* This is equal to 50 */
var cell_width_num = 50; /* This is also equal to 50 */
for (var i = 0; i < cell_height_num; i++) {
    var tr = $("<tr></tr>").appendTo(container);
    for (var j = 0; j < cell_width_num; j++) {
        tr.append($("<td></td>", {
            css: {
                width: "1px",
                height: "1px",
                backgroundColor: colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]
            }
        }));
    }
}
```